# webapp2 + RESTful API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am building on Google App Engine + Python + webapp2. Part of building a modern web app requires a restful API. I know that I can do this with `Flask`, however I want to explore the possibility of building a REST API on `webapp2`.

On webapp2, requests are handled like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/post/new', CreatePost),
    ('/post/([a-z0-9]+)', ViewPost),
    ('/post/([a-z0-9]+)/edit', EditPost),
    ('/post/([a-z0-9]+)/delete', DeletePost)
])
```

Note: `([a-z0-9]+)` is a regex that represents the `post_id`

The above request handlers do not adhere to a RESTful pattern since the request `methods` are specified in the path (/delete, /edit, /new) rather than in the request headers.

Is the solution to create a single handler class that receives all request types? For example:

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # handle GET requests

    def post(self):
        # handle POST requests

    def put(self):
        # handle PUT requests

    def delete(self):
        # handle DELETE requests


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/post/?', PostHandler)
])
```

In this case, all `/post` paths are handled by PostHandler. The `post_id` is no longer used in this pattern since it would be submitted in the request body instead.

Is this the correct approach to building a REST API with webapp2?

Comment: Why not use a JSON request which contains the action (create..delete) and the data. It is easy extendable and also benefits your js client.

Comment: There is a related project on github "RestAPI for Webapp2" https://github.com/budowski/rest_gae

Comment: @voscausa, just to clarify, do you mean to send the request in JSON where one of its properties is the method name? Example: `{ method: "DELETE", data: { ... }, ... }`

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz, ty for the suggestion. I am avoiding a library if I am able to do without it — unless it is too complicated to do without it.

Comment: Yes.  And in the webapp2 request handler you code something like : jsonobject = json.loads(self.request.body)

Comment: @voscausa Interesting approach. What would be the advantage of this approach over creating the get/post/put/delete functions? Most http libraries (like axios) will require the the `method` parameter.

Comment: It is good practice to seprate header like info from te data.

Comment: @puoygae IIUC, it is only REST if you actually use the http method by specifying it in the header ("method=PUT" and likewise).

Comment: But in general I like a single endpoiny API like GraphQl.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, but you should continue to handle `post_id` in the url and do it like this:

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, post_id=None):
        if post_id:
            # handle Fetching a single post object
        else:
            # handle Queries

    def post(self, post_id=None):
        if post_id:
            self.abort(405)
        # handle creating a single post object

    def put(self, post_id=None):
        if post_id:
            # handle updating a single post object
        else:
            self.abort(405)


    def delete(self, post_id=None):
        if post_id:
            # handle deleting a single post object
        else:
            self.abort(405)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/post/<post_id>/', PostHandler),
    ('/post/', PostHandler),
])
```

Furthermore putting the HTTP verb within the request payload like `voscausa` suggested is not inline with RESTful API design.

Answer (score 0):

One should extend `webapp2.RequestHandler` and use the extension as the new base class for a `RESTfulHandler` and then maybe also for your specific purpose extend the `RESTfulHandler` to a `RESTfulPostHandler`. This way we could also deal with new ways or work such as jwt (JSON web token) in the header, authorization and other properties that you wish to handle in the header.

BTW, "post" might not be the best name for your item/object since it could easily get mixed up with the http verb "post". If I were you, I would rename it into "item" or similar, and use a `RESTfulItemHandler` which extends the webapp2 request handler. There are many things you would like to share between your handler and like that it is convenient to share the functionality in a base-class.

Comment: Creating a special class that handles that extends the webapp2.RequestHandler is a good idea. Had not thought of this.